# image expands link trigger range on full width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a mobile menu with some items in there. Each item is a link. The first item is the logo the other items are text based links.

The text based link is just as big as its text. So the link won't trigger if I click on the div container.

I provide a full example for my question

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#btnMenu").click(() => {
    toggleMenu();
  });

  $(".navbarLink").click(() => {
    if ($("#navbarItems").hasClass("activeNavbar")) {
      toggleMenu();
    }
  });
});

function toggleMenu() {
  $("#navbarItems").toggleClass("activeNavbar");
  toggleMenuBtn();
}

function toggleMenuBtn() {
  $("#btnMenu").toggleClass("activeMenuBtn");
}
```

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  background: #1e222a;
}

#navbarItems {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logoLink {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbarItemContainer {
  background: #1e222a;
}

.navbarLink {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbarLink:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

#btnMenuContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#btnMenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuBtnBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.activeMenuBtn #barTop {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.activeMenuBtn #barCenter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.activeMenuBtn #barBottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #navbar {
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  #navbar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  #navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #676767;
  }
  #btnMenuContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #btnMenu {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #navbarItems {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #logoLink {
    display: block;
  }
  .navbarItem {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
  }
  #navbarItems.activeNavbar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="btnMenuContainer">
    <div id="btnMenu">
      <div id="barTop" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
      <div id="barCenter" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
      <div id="barBottom" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarItems">
    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a id="logoLink" class="link navbarLink" href="#">
          <img class="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ph03nyx/super-mario/128/Hat-Mario-icon.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a class="link navbarLink" href="#sectionTwo">
                    Link 2
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a class="link navbarLink" href="#sectionThree">
                    Link 3
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you check the logo container you will see that the link will trigger on the whole width of the div container. Normally I only want the link trigger on the img click. How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see that behaviour because there's a CSS of `display: block` set to the `#logoLink`

```
#logoLink {
  display: block;
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#btnMenu").click(() => {
    toggleMenu();
  });

  $(".navbarLink").click(() => {
    if ($("#navbarItems").hasClass("activeNavbar")) {
      toggleMenu();
    }
  });
});

function toggleMenu() {
  $("#navbarItems").toggleClass("activeNavbar");
  toggleMenuBtn();
}

function toggleMenuBtn() {
  $("#btnMenu").toggleClass("activeMenuBtn");
}
```

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  background: #1e222a;
}

#navbarItems {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logoLink {
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
}

#navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbarItemContainer {
  background: #1e222a;
}

.navbarLink {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbarLink:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

#btnMenuContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#btnMenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuBtnBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.activeMenuBtn #barTop {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.activeMenuBtn #barCenter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.activeMenuBtn #barBottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #navbar {
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  #navbar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  #navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #676767;
  }
  #btnMenuContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #btnMenu {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #navbarItems {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #logoLink {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .navbarItem {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
  }
  #navbarItems.activeNavbar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="btnMenuContainer">
    <div id="btnMenu">
      <div id="barTop" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
      <div id="barCenter" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
      <div id="barBottom" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarItems">
    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a id="logoLink" class="link navbarLink" href="#">
          <img class="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ph03nyx/super-mario/128/Hat-Mario-icon.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a class="link navbarLink" href="#sectionTwo">
                    Link 2
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a class="link navbarLink" href="#sectionThree">
                    Link 3
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change that to `display: inline-block` and you'll see the change i.e. only the image will be clickable.
[Here's](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/) a good reference to read about the `display` property.

Answer (score 1):

Your anchor with id `#logolink` has `display: block` (or `display: flex` depending on the viewport size), so it expands to fill it's container. I removed those styles, and it seems to behave how you want, only registering a hover when over the actual image.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#btnMenu").click(() => {
    toggleMenu();
  });

  $(".navbarLink").click(() => {
    if ($("#navbarItems").hasClass("activeNavbar")) {
      toggleMenu();
    }
  });
});

function toggleMenu() {
  $("#navbarItems").toggleClass("activeNavbar");
  toggleMenuBtn();
}

function toggleMenuBtn() {
  $("#btnMenu").toggleClass("activeMenuBtn");
}
```

```css
.link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

#navbar {
  height: 60px;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  background: #1e222a;
}

#navbarItems {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#logoLink {
  
}

#navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.navbarItemContainer {
  background: #1e222a;
}

.navbarLink {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.navbarLink:hover {
  color: #3abcf3;
}

#btnMenuContainer {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
}

#btnMenu {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menuBtnBar {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  margin: 6px 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.activeMenuBtn #barTop {
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.activeMenuBtn #barCenter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.activeMenuBtn #barBottom {
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}

@media(max-width: 1200px) {
  #navbar {
    padding-left: 150px;
    padding-right: 150px;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1100px) {
  #navbar {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  #navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  #navbarItems .navbarItemContainer:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #676767;
  }
  #btnMenuContainer {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
  }
  #btnMenu {
    margin-left: 20px;
  }
  #navbarItems {
    margin-left: 0;
    display: none;
  }
  #logoLink {
    
  }
  .navbarItem {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px 0;
  }
  #navbarItems.activeNavbar {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="btnMenuContainer">
    <div id="btnMenu">
      <div id="barTop" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
      <div id="barCenter" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
      <div id="barBottom" class="menuBtnBar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="navbarItems">
    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a id="logoLink" class="link navbarLink" href="#">
          <img class="img" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/ph03nyx/super-mario/128/Hat-Mario-icon.png">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a class="link navbarLink" href="#sectionTwo">
                    Link 2
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="navbarItemContainer">
      <div class="navbarItem">
        <a class="link navbarLink" href="#sectionThree">
                    Link 3
                </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```